# how can I set text of input?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I set text of input like below

```
document.getElementById("102_inputText").value="2,550"
```

this is element

```
<input type="text" dir="ltr" ng-style="{'text-align': tpAlign}" ng-model="inputVal" ng-disabled="tpDisabled" ng-change="changeVal()" id="102_inputText" placeholder="" maxlength="10" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched">
```

but when I click button it gives me error that fill the input

another thing that is strange to me is when I open this page a week ago

this element has id of 100_inputText and two days ago it has another thing

Comment: It seems that you use AngularJS. Your value is defined by the inputVal variable. You may change that instead. eg. inputVal = "2,550"

Comment: thanks can yoy explain it by code@kirschkern

Comment: I've given an example. To be more precise we need more context. Are you trying to change something in an existing project? You probably need to learn some angular basics first.

Comment: yes I am trying to change something in an existing website so I can upload html file of this website. Is it enough for you to help me? I really need it now. later I have enough time to learn angular js@kirschkern

Answer (score 0):

Have you try
`document.getElementById("102_inputText").setAttribute('value', '2,550');`
?